# How to print C++ unit test result during runtime

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have been tasked to write unit tests for some embedded software and since the tests are being written after the software the only viable option is to run tests on the board and print the result to the serial output.

I have written a function that will accept a Boolean statement and log the result of the test, but I am wondering if functions such as `EXPECT_EQ` (from GoogleTest) or `CHECK_EQUAL` (from Cpputest) return the result as a string or something that can be logged.

Do either of these functions (or maybe a function from another testing framework) return the result of the test so that it can be printed?

Essentially, when a test fails, I want to be able to print something like "FAILED: expected x, but got y".

Comment: The whole idea of unit test is that you can test code anywhere through injecting mocks/stubs. So instead of setting a register directly you set a value to an object/interface (which on the real system is a real register). Then you can at least test all your logic before going to test/debug on real hardware. You can send test number + bool over serial port maybe you need to wrap the provided macros to do that e.g. FW_EXPECT_EQ (go to serial on hardware, to EXPECT_EQ on unit tests on PC)

Comment: Both the test frameworks can output test results to files. You can run the tests and transfer files are tests finish.

Comment: *"since the tests are being written after the software"* -- it would be tough to run the tests before they had something to test.